# How to remove a javascript function in the previous page on jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a site made up of various html pages in jQuery mobile. On one page I have a javascript function in the content. Upon going to another page, this function still exists. How can I remove it before displaying the next page?

I am using the following, which removes the dom elements on the previous page, but the javascript functions from the previous page are still available.

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
});
$('div').live('pagehide', function(event) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

Here's the full code of two pages. Upon clicking from page 1 to page 2, the function testContent which is only on page 1 still works.

Page 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Page 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
    doPageShow();
});
$('div').live('pagehide', function(event) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-cache="never">
<div data-role="content">
<h1>Page 1z</h1>
<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
<div id="test"></div><!-- this div should be removed upon going to the next page -->
<script>
function testContent() {
    // this function still exists on the next page, how can it be removed?
    alert("testContent");
}
function doPageShow() {
    alert("Page 1");
    alert($("#test").length); // shows 1 which is correct
    testContent(); // function is on this page, so it works
}
</script>
</div><!--content-->
</div><!--page-->
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Page 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
    doPageShow();
});
$('div').live('pagehide', function(event) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-cache="never">
<div data-role="content">
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
<script>
function doPageShow() {
    alert("Page 2");
    alert($("#test").length); // shows 0 which is correct
    testContent(); // why does this still work???
}
</script>
</div><!--content-->
</div><!--page-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap you code in `pageshow` using `.on` and disable them on `pagehide` using `.off`. Note that `.live` is deprecated and replaced with `.on`.

Comment: I tried on, but it still persists.

Comment: try `$(document).off("pageshow").on("pageshow", function () { //code });` this will remove previous bindings. another option, use `$.mobile.changePage("page1.html", { reloadPage: true });` this will force reload page and removes previous objects and bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects live until the page refreshes. This is one of the advantages of jquery mobile, as parsing JS can take a long time on mobile devices, it is considered better to do it once.

If you really need to you could set the function to null.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. Basically in JavaScript a function is just another object like:

doPageShow = function(){...}

Everything set in javascript persists on subsequent ajax loaded pages, so if I set a variable in one page, it will still have that value in another ajax loaded page, including functions.